# once you reach home/have reached home

Tags: present-perfect

Call me once you reach home.

vs

Call me once you have reached home.

what is the difference?

also

I'll only be satisfied after I pass my test with good marks.

vs

I'll only be satisfied after I have passed my test with good marks.

which one is more correct?

Does the use of simple present mean the activity is performed at the very instant of reaching home or say passing the exam, and the use of present perfect means sometimes after the say reaching home or passing the exam ?

Comment: The difference is not temporal.  When you reach home, you arrive there.  When you have reached home, you're fully there.

Answer (score 1):

By using the present perfect, you are saying you have recently completed this action. This is a point in time. By using the simple perfect, all you're saying is that it happened sometime in the period before now. It is much less precise.

So if you're saying your satisfaction will occur immediately after the passing, 'have passed' is probably more appropriate. If you're speaking in broader terms, that your life won't have satisfaction until this thing is done, the broader simple perfect is more appropriate.